# Getting error in variable holder on accessing another view holder in Recycler View

Tags: android, string, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am declaring 2 Strings in `getItemCount()` in my java class file

**see my code**

```
package com.example.quizapp;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList;

    public CategoryAdapter(List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList) {
        this.categoryModelList = categoryModelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_item,parent,false);
        return new viewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       holder.setData(categoryModelList.get(position).getImageUrl(),categoryModelList.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryModelList.size();
    }

    class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private CircleImageView imageView;
        private TextView title;
        private String url;

        public viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        }
        private void setData(String url, String title){
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext()).load(url).into(imageView);
            this.title.setText(title);
        }
    }
}
```

I have to create a method `setData` and in this method, two string data type passed `URL` and `title` but both are not working when I am trying to access these in this method

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       holder.setData(categoryModelList.get(position).getImageUrl(),categoryModelList.get(position).getTitle());
    }
```

this is not working in the `onBindViewHolder`

**error image**
[image]

**Error Message:**

```
error: cannot find symbol
        holder.setData(categoryModelList.get(position).getImageUrl(),categoryModelList.get(position).getTitle());
              ^
  symbol:   method setData(String,String)
  location: variable holder of type ViewHolder
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Root cause**

`setData()` is a method of `viewholder` class, but inside `onBindViewHolder`, the `holder` variable is an instance of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, that why the compiler throw that error.

**Solution**

Cast the `holder` to your `viewholder` class. Change your code from

```
holder.setData(categoryModelList.get(position).getImageUrl(),categoryModelList.get(position).getTitle());
```

to

```
String url = categoryModelList.get(position).getImageUrl();
String title = categoryModelList.get(position).getTitle();
((viewholder) holder).setData(url, title);
```